# How to set variable in render with reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I have a Reactjs render method and I am trying to set a variable through a function. It looks like this (you guessed it , does not work):

```
render() {
        let myVariable=''

        //this function changes/sets myVariable
        this.changeMyVariable()

        return (
            <div>{myVariable}</div>
        );
}
```

How can I set a variable that is used in my render through another function, something like the example above. I also tried to use a state variable but the `changeMyVariable()` function runs twice.

Comment: Probably you're chasing an anti-pattern and didn't understand the react way of thinking.

Comment: That comment by Inanc cracked me up.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
render() {
    // assuming 'changeMyVariable' returns a value
    const myVariable = this.changeMyVariable();

    return (
        <div>{myVariable}</div>
    );
}
```

Actually you can invoke the function inside your JSX itself:

`<div>{this.changeMyVariable()}</div>`.

**Note**: If the output of `this.changeMyVariable()` never changes based on new props, it is better to compute the value outside `render` (avoid re-calculating when component re-renders).

Answer (score 2):

Although you can set local variables in the render, the use of [`props`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/components-and-props.html) is recommended for better modifiability.

So, you first 'declare' the property in the component:

```
class ExampleComponent extends React.Component {
    static propTypes = {
        myVariable: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    };    
    static defaultProps = {
        myVariable: 'Default Value'
    };
```

And then, you render this `prop` at the `ExampleComponent` render method:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>{this.props.myVariable}</div>
    );
}
```

---

To use this `prop` when you render `ExampleComponent`:

```
render() {
    <ExampleComponent myVariable='example'/>
}
```